# Moving the same byte to each address between two distinct address?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

Is it at all possible to move the same byte to a bunch of addresses quickly

```
pseudocode...
mov ax, 10
mov [memAddrStart to MemAddrEnd], ax
```

This would put AX into every single address, so I could reference any address in the sequence and always fetch 10.

Is this possible, and if not, how can I go around it?

Comment: Check out `rep stosb`

Comment: In general no that is not the kind of thing you typically find in an instruction set but...x86 is special...in general you perform a loop to do such a thing.  look at the hand tuned memsets for various architectures in glibc and newlib and other open source C libraries.

Comment: Just FYI, this operation of filling a range of memory with the same value is called `memset` in C.  Google on that for examples of doing it in asm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an instruction specifically designed for this.

It does need a bit of setting up though.

```
cld                                     //CLear the Direction flag (optional, see below)
mov al,10                               //we are moving bytes
mov edi,MemAddrStart                    //Destination = start
mov ecx,(MemAddrEnd - MemAddrStart)+ 1  //Count = (end-start)+1
rep stosb                               //(REP)repeat (STOS)storing (B)bytes until done
```

See: [STOSB documentation](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/STOS:STOSB:STOSW:STOSD:STOSQ.html).

**Direction flag**
[The `direction` flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_flag) determines whether `rep stosx` moves forward or backward. 
You should **always** leave it moving forward, because that's the default direction.
If you set it to backwards, using [`std`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/STD.html), then make sure you reset it back to normal using [`cld`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CLD.html) afterwards. If you don't, bad things may happen, because many compilers and operating systems assume the direction flag is always clear.

**'[...] if not, how do I go about it?'**
You can of course program this using a simple loop:

```
mov al,10                               //we are moving bytes
mov edi,MemAddrStart                    //destination = start
mov ecx,(MemAddrEnd - MemAddrStart)+ 1  //length = (end-start)+1
Loop:
dec ecx                                 //This is
mov [edi+ecx],al                        //what `rep stosb` 
jnz Loop                                //does
```

Note that for efficiency and simplicity my loop starts at the end and works its way back. `stos` (with the direction flag cleared) starts at the beginning. Otherwise the two work the same.
Because I'm DECreasing `ecx`, I can use the implicit test for zero (`jnz`) and don't need to add another test or another register to see if I'm done.

**Remarks on your sample code**

```
mov ax, 10
mov [memAddrStart to MemAddrEnd], ax
```

This code moves a word (16 bits). This writes the bytes

```
Address        HEX   DEC
MemAddrStart:   0A    10
MemAddrStart+1: 00    00
```

To memory, not what you want, if you do the following in a loop:

```
dec ecx 
mov [edi+ecx],ax           
jnz Loop
```

You will write the following:

```
Address        HEX   DEC
MemAddrStart:   0A    10
MemAddrStart+1: 0A    10
....
MemAddrEnd      0A    10
MemAddrEnd+1    00    00  <<-- Oops, you're writing past the buffer.
```

This is known as [a buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), which is an error that can cause all sorts of nasty problems.

If you want to store words then you'll have to alter your code to do so.(`mov ecx,(end-start+1)/2`  `rep stosw`).

Comment: Thank you very much for this - I appreciate the detail!

Comment: It's funny that you should warn about buffer overflow, when you yourself wrote one in your example loop!

Comment: The calculation of `ECX` in preparation of storing words was not correct.

Comment: @SepRoland, note to self, don't publish untested code.